# Android App crashes after Scrolling down ListView

Tags: java, android, android-listview, adapter

I have a listView, everything's working fine whan I don't have too much items on it.. When the list of items is long when I scroll down it crashes at a certain point...

This is my adapter code :

```
public class SearchListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private JsonArray searchResults;

public SearchListViewAdapter(Context context, JsonArray searchResults) {
    this.searchResults = searchResults;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return searchResults.count();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return searchResults.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    JsonObject searchResult = (JsonObject)getItem (position);
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_search_result, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtFullName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.FullName);
        holder.txtDateScan = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.DateScan);
        holder.txtBarcodeKeyword = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.BarcodeKeyword);
        holder.txtHourScan = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.HourScan);
        holder.imgScanStatus = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ScanStatus);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtFullName.setText(searchResult.getString ("FirstName") + searchResult.getString ("LastName"));
    holder.txtBarcodeKeyword.setText(searchResult.getString("Barcode"));

    JsonObject ScanInfo = null;
    try {
        ScanInfo = searchResult.getObject("ScanInfo");
    } catch (JsonException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String LastScanTime[] = ScanInfo.getString("LastScanTime").split(" ");

    holder.txtDateScan.setText(LastScanTime[0]);

    try {
        if(ScanInfo.getInt("Scans") == 0 || StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(ScanInfo.getString("Scans")))
            holder.imgScanStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
        else if(ScanInfo.getInt("Scans") % 2 == 0)
            holder.imgScanStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.orange);
        else if(ScanInfo.getInt("Scans") % 2 == 1)
            holder.imgScanStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.green);
    } catch (JsonException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    holder.txtHourScan.setText(LastScanTime[1]);

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtFullName;
    TextView txtDateScan;
    TextView txtBarcodeKeyword;
    TextView txtHourScan;
    ImageView imgScanStatus;
}
}
```

and the Logcat :

```
09-22 16:35:31.191: E/AndroidRuntime(31440): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-22 16:35:31.191: E/AndroidRuntime(31440): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-22 16:35:31.191: E/AndroidRuntime(31440):    at com.eventpulse.app.SearchListViewAdapter.getView(SearchListViewAdapter.java:72)
09-22 16:35:31.191: E/AndroidRuntime(31440):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
09-22 16:35:31.191: E/AndroidRuntime(31440):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1769)
09-22 16:35:31.191: E/AndroidRuntime(31440):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
09-22 16:35:31.191: E/AndroidRuntime(31440):    at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:636)
09-22 16:35:31.191: E/AndroidRuntime(31440):    at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5040)
09-22 16:35:31.191: E/AndroidRuntime(31440):    at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4197)
09-22 16:35:31.191: E/AndroidRuntime(31440):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
09-22 16:35:31.191: E/AndroidRuntime(31440):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
09-22 16:35:31.191: E/AndroidRuntime(31440):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:524)
09-22 16:35:31.191: E/AndroidRuntime(31440):    at   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
09-22 16:35:31.191: E/AndroidRuntime(31440):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-22 16:35:31.191: E/AndroidRuntime(31440):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-22 16:35:31.191: E/AndroidRuntime(31440):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-22 16:35:31.191: E/AndroidRuntime(31440):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-22 16:35:31.191: E/AndroidRuntime(31440):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-22 16:35:31.191: E/AndroidRuntime(31440):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-22 16:35:31.191: E/AndroidRuntime(31440):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-22 16:35:31.191: E/AndroidRuntime(31440):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-22 16:35:31.191: E/AndroidRuntime(31440):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Could you help me please, it's goind to drive me crazy!

Thank you.

**EDIT :** line 72 : `String LastScanTime[] = ScanInfo.getString("LastScanTime").split(" ");`

It may be something related to this post : [Android ListView throwing NullPointerException when I try to scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824378/android-listview-throwing-nullpointerexception-when-i-try-to-scroll)

Comment: May i know what is 72 line...

Comment: yeah, it is hard to tell without knowing which one is 72 line

Comment: Please click on this line **09-22 16:35:31.191: E/AndroidRuntime(31440):    at com.eventpulse.app.SearchListViewAdapter.getView(SearchListViewAdapter.java:72)** from your logcat and tell us which line it denotes.

Comment: print this line in log.. ScanInfo.getString("LastScanTime") and post to us..

Comment: Maybe `LastScanTime[0]` is null? 

`String LastScanTime[] = ScanInfo.getString("LastScanTime").split("  ");` you can add a line after it to print the contents of `LastScanTime`.

Comment: The ListView is getting filled by the content of the JSon.. So it can't be `ScanInfo.getString("LastScanTime").split(" ");` empty..

Comment: then print that content in log in every count..  ScanInfo.getString("LastScanTime")

Comment: @Tamilan thank you for your interest.. but when I do `Log.d("ScanInfo", ScanInfo.getString("LastScanTime"));` I don't really get anything !!

Comment: @Mehdi that's y that null pointer error came.. then print this ScanInfo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with you Json code any of json object is being null you shall take care with this and check for the values of null before applying

You shall do by checking the null valuse

```
if(mJsonObject!=null)
{
// Then perform you task
}
```

Your code check at suspected location for null
like  **ScanInfo** or **LastScanTime**

```
  holder.txtFullName.setText(searchResult.getString ("FirstName") + searchResult.getString ("LastName"));
    holder.txtBarcodeKeyword.setText(searchResult.getString("Barcode"));

    JsonObject ScanInfo = null;
    try {
        ScanInfo = searchResult.getObject("ScanInfo");
    } catch (JsonException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String LastScanTime[] = ScanInfo.getString("LastScanTime").split(" "); // May be here its not getting values and unable to split the content

    holder.txtDateScan.setText(LastScanTime[0]); // if thats false may be LastScanTime is null
    try {
        if(ScanInfo.getInt("Scans") == 0 || StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(ScanInfo.getString("Scans")))
            holder.imgScanStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
        else if(ScanInfo.getInt("Scans") % 2 == 0)
            holder.imgScanStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.orange);
        else if(ScanInfo.getInt("Scans") % 2 == 1)
            holder.imgScanStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.green);
    } catch (JsonException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    holder.txtHourScan.setText(LastScanTime[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that the listview and its elements are displayed !! the crash happens only when I scroll down IF the list is LONG... like this guy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824378/android-listview-throwing-nullpointerexception-when-i-try-to-scroll

Comment: That was exactly that... The JSon I've gotten was corrupted by the server and the 2 last records don't have an `ScanInfo` element.. That's exactly why..

Comment: Yes i was suspecting that